# How to capture button click event from asp.net DataList

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a DataList control in asp.net webform, inside this DataLIst I have 2 labels that are bound to database, and one button.
One of the label represent Id and other one Stock.
I want to capture the button click event of specific product, and then add that product to the user cart.

Here is my datalist:

```
 <asp:DataList ID="dListProduct" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4" OnItemCommand="dListProduct_ItemCommand">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div>
                    <table class="table-responsive" border="1">                    
                        <tr>
                             <td>
                                  <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Available Stock: " ></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Stock")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                             <td>
                                  <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Id" ></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="lblPId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Product_Id")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                             <td>
                                 <asp:Button id="btnAddtoCart" runat="server" Text="Add to Cart"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
```

Here is the code I am using in OnItemCommand Event of DataList:

```
 protected void dListProduct_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            Label lbl = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblPId");
            Response.Write(lbl.Text);
        }
```

but this code never get executed.
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You have to add an `OnClick` event to the `Button` in orderto capture the `click` event

Comment: ok, but in this scenario how can i determine which product's button is clicked? there will be more than 1 buttons on the page, i want to get the id of the respective product on button click

Comment: @Chaitanya, the [documentation for ItemCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.itemcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) specifically states "Occurs when any button is clicked in the DataList control." Why must OP use `OnClick`?

Comment: @Usman Add `CommandName`, `CommandArgument` for the button to uniquely identify the `buttons`

Comment: its still not working.. any other idea to solve this issue? or an alternate way to achieve this?

Comment: @UsmanFarooq, how and where are you binding the DataList? Are you binding it on every PostBack?

Comment: no, i m binding it in if(!isPostBack)

Comment: @UsmanFarooq - OK. I'm not sure then. I've copied your code and it works as expected for me. `ItemCommand` is called when clicking the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy and paste the code below exactly the way I have it.

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class DataListExample : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            this.BindData();
        }
    }

    private void BindData()
    {
        MyStock stock1 = new MyStock { Product_Id = 1, Stock = "Stock 1" };
        MyStock stock2 = new MyStock { Product_Id = 2, Stock = "Stock 2" };
        dListProduct.DataSource = new List<MyStock> { stock1, stock2 };
        dListProduct.DataBind();
    }

    protected void dListProduct_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        Label lbl = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblPId");
        Response.Write(lbl.Text);
    }
}

public class MyStock
{
    public int Product_Id { get; set; }
    public string Stock { get; set; }
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<asp:DataList ID="dListProduct" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4" OnItemCommand="dListProduct_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            <table class="table-responsive" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Available Stock: "></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Stock")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Id"></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="lblPId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Product_Id")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnAddtoCart" runat="server" Text="Add to Cart" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```